# How to update a column using another column value?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

I have an empty table with rows that have `timestamp` and `file_url` columns.

When I add a row, `timestamp` is filled with Postgres `current_timestamp` value. At the same moment, I want to put into `file_url` the same value, but formatted differently.

`timestamp` can have this format: `2018-07-26 08:37:56.749125`
and for `file_url` I want to have something like `http://somedomain.com/files/20180726083756.749125.jpg`.

How can I do it in one run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try using the `TO_CHAR` function on your timestamp:

```
select to_char(timestamp '2018-07-26 08:37:56.749125', 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS.MS');
```

This would output `20180726083756.749`.  If you want to build a URL, then you may also do that with string concatenation, e.g.

```
INSERT INTO yourTable (ts_col, file_url)
SELECT
    current_timestamp,
    'http://somedomain.com/files/' ||
    TO_CHAR(current_timestamp, 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS.MS') || '.jpg';
```

Comment: ``current_timestamp`` will have same value inside one transaction, so it is safe to use it for calculation of different columns.
see [postgres docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT)

Comment: What behavior do you actually want?

Comment: please note, using ``current_timestamp`` will cause non-unique names if you insert more than one record in one transaction, that might be undesired behavior. If you do only single insert per transaction - it is good solution.

Comment: Well, to wax philosophical here, if the inserts really happened at different points in time, then wouldn't you want different timestamps?

Comment: I agree, that it is more expected to have different timestamps for each insert but in fact you'll have the same value [see psql example](https://gist.github.com/ddobrotvorskiy/7753495612d298ee25a238d05b164a91)